# tensorflow: Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

So im trying to do some machine learning, and i want to make use of my gpu.
Im on tensorflow version 2.6.0(i also tried tensorflow-gpu).I installed CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1. Added everything to PATH like it says here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu. However i still get the error that it cant find the cudart64_110.dll. The file even is in the 'NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin' directory. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error today. In previous version of tf, I need to install a Nvidia toolkit to get the file.

Here is the right toolkit for the cudart64_110.dll file: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.3.0-download-archive

Then just follow the installation guide. If you need more help or it doesnt work, just write it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely due to three issues:

1. You haven't installed CUDA and CUDNN from Nvidia.
2. You don't have an NVIDIA graphics card on your computer (integrated or external )
3. having an outdated Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio if you are using a Windows.
   go ahead to [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170.) and install an updated version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable that fits your system.

If you checklist all the above , you won't have any error messages like that.