# Dynamic library cudart64_110.dll can not be loaded

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, jupyter

When I run **python Script** that uses **Tensorflow** I receive this warning message in command line

```
Could not load dynamic library cudart64_110
cudart64_110.not found
```

How can I solve this error when using **Tensorflow** and How can I use **GPU** and enable it when using **TensorFlow**?

Comment: Tensorflow doc: [GPU support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu?hl=en)

Comment: Does this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69575516/14290681), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910708/14290681) answer your question? Thanks!